# Orange indicator light is on for my outdoor GFI receptacle

Tags: electrical

Why is my GFI showing an orange indicator light? I have tried the reset a few times I have tried to unplug and plug back in. It remains orange.

Comment: What make and model is said GFCI?

Comment: There isn't a standard set of colors for GFCIs. You might as well be saying you have a blue light on front of your computer.   We couldn't even start into an answer without asking the model number of the GFCI, but all we're gonna do is google the instructions, and read them to see what an orange light means.  Maybe you can do that part, which I'm sure will raise a new question... you can [edit] this question to then ask that.

Comment: If you can't reset it even with loads unplugged, be aware there could be other GFCI plugs protected by the same plug, so if there is a ground fault load plugged into one of those it will trip when you try to reset.

Comment: What is it that you unplugged? Was it the thing plugged into the receptacle? Was it the receptacle itself (where "unplugged" means removed the wires & reattached)? How do you unplug a receptacle? Also, at a minimum, clear, focused pics of the outlet in question, preferably with the outlet pulled out of the box and all the wiring _still attached_.

Answer (score 1):

Orange? I don’t think I have seen but if the outside GFCI is not WR or weather rated moisture may have gotten to the electronics affecting the power to the led or be the cause of the trip.

Moisture in another receptacle that is fed by that one could also cause the trip/ failure to reset problem.

I have found many boxes outside with water in them not enough conductance to trip a breaker but in some cases enough rust and dirt in the water to trip the GFCI.

In-use or heavy duty covers on receptacles in wet locations help prevent this problem when combined with WR rated GFCI circuitry (receptacles). The electronics in WR GFCI’s are coated so moisture won’t affect them but if some current is going to ground through water at the terminals that can cause the problem.